# What is the purpose setting a bound function with the same name?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain to me the purpose of JavaScript code like this:

```
this._handleBlah = this._handleBlah.bind(this);
```

It appears in a constructor and this pattern seems to be used across a code base I'm reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's useful when the "member" functions are going to be used as event handlers, or in other similar callback situations. The bound versions will have the correct `this` value.